# select query not executing correctly in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi in the below code select query executing but output giving 3 times all the record values.
For example where I am passing username as user2 it giving output `45New45New45New46New46New46New47New47New47NewSUCCESSFULLY`
But In my database it contains only 3 records:

```
id       47  48 49
groupname:New New New
```

I am expeting output above one.But I am getting 3 times.

Where I did the mistake.

**php**

```
case "DispalyGroupDetails":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);

        if ($userId != NULL)

        {

            if (isset($_REQUEST['username']))           
            {               
                 $username = $_REQUEST['username'];



                 $sql = "select Id from users where username='$username' limit 1";

                 if ($result = $db->query($sql))

                 {
                        if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))

                        {    

                                     $sql = "select g.id,g.groupname from `users` u, `friends` f,`group` g 
                                     where u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId";
                                    $theResult = $db->query($sql);

                                     if ($theResult) {
                        //$theRow = $db->fetchObject($theResult);
                        while( $theRow = $db->fetchObject($theResult))
                        { 
                        echo $theRow->id; 
                        echo $theRow->groupname;
                        }       
                                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                } else {
                                        $out = FAILED;
                                }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;                      
                        }
                 }

                 else
                 {
                        $out = FAILED;
                 }              
            }

            else
            {
                    $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
```

Comment: Just play this : 
select g.id,g.groupname 
from `users` u, `friends` f,`group` g 
where u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId;

You should get more than 3 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your select statement:

```
SELECT g.id,g.groupname 
FROM users u, friends f, group g 
WHERE u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId
```

You are joining three tables, users, friends and groups. This will yield several rows containing `groupname` and `group.id`. If you have the possibility, try executing your query in `PHPMyAdmin` or a similar tool and you will see that the table returned by your query contains more than three rows, each having `g.id` and `g.groupname`.

The easiest way to get groupname and id only once is to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT g.id,g.groupname 
FROM users u, friends f, group g 
WHERE u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId
GROUP BY g.id, g.groupname
```

To read more about how `JOINS` work, you can read this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163615/sql-join-returning-multiple-rows-when-i-only-want-one-row).

Answer (score 0):

You use echo $theRow->id; , so all the results about this row are print.